# possible to paste 'in place' into textmate without line breaks and affecting other text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textmate

I use Textmate for most of my text editing. One thing I would like to do is to be able to past a multiline piece of text into a selected space and not cause line breaks to surrounding text. I am not sure if this is at all possible. I have included a screenshot of the selection that I want to paste into:

[image]

Basically, I want to copy in a chunk of text (a git repo shown via tree -a) and be able to compare line-by-line. I have tried the various modes but to no success. I'm thiking this would need to filter out the new lines but think there might be a way to automate this. Is this possible?

Comment: This isn't really related to RoR or git. It's a text editor question.

Comment: fair enough, I removed those tags - figured most likely to get answered via tagging to one of those.